# Restrict value of attribute to one of several values in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

How do I code the definition of an attribute in an XSD such that its value is restricted to one of several possible values? I don't want a regular expression or anything complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Define a simple type, typically a restriction of xs:string, that lists the allowed values in its xs:enumeration facets.

(To be frank, I fail to see how you could have difficulty finding this information. I hope you aren't using StackOverflow as a substitute for reading the documentation.)